# Can aws-sdk-cpp be built for QNX?

Tags: qnx, aws-sdk-cpp

The goal is to upload to Amazon S3 from QNX software.

Is it possible to target QNX as the build for the aws-sdk-cpp?

Initial attempts seem to default to Windows.

Comment: What is the version of QNX you gonna use ???

Comment: @OlegGopkolov We will use QNX 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know, but you should try. Since QNX is unix like system, most probably it's okay to build on QNX. But make sure you have openssl/curl/cmake stuff installed.